# Best Practices for Storing Digital Certificate

Tags: cryptography, certificates, java, digital-signature

I'm building an application where certain sensitive files need to be digitally signed before being stored in the file system using ASN.1 encoding, so they can be verified against a digital certificate (the one corresponding to the private key used for signing) at a later point in time when they're accessed. I'm using the Bouncy Castle library for Java.

There's a disagreement between members of my team regarding the best place for storing the digital certificate, and I'd like to know what's the best practice:

- Storing the file contents, the signature and the certificate packaged together in a [CMSSignedData](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/bouncycastle/bcmail-jdk14/1.45/bcmail-jdk14-1.45-javadoc.jar!/org/bouncycastle/cms/CMSSignedData.html) object. In  this way, the verification procedure only needs to receive the CMSSignedData object, as all data needed for performing the verification is present in a single object.
- Storing only the signature and the file contents in a CMSSignedData, and storing the certificate elsewhere. Using this approach, some extra work is needed for 
  managing the certificate and relating each signed file to the certificate needed for performing the verification.

I'm worried about the first approach, I believe someone could package and save the file contents, a certificate different from my own and a signature generated with the private key corresponding to that certificate - and the verification would succeed, because the verification procedure didn't receive the "original" certificate but a fake one.

What do you recommend? Do you see any shortcomings or potential problems in either one of the alternatives mentioned above? what's the best practice, or should I use an entirely different approach?

Comment: You seem to be confusing the certificate with the private key. It's the private key that needs to be protected, not the certificate. The certificate is needed for verification, not the private key.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz there's no confusion, the question is: where should I store the certificate for performing validations later? For instance, in the first approach someone could package and save the file contents, a certificate _different_ from my own and a signature generated with the private key corresponding to that certificate - and the verification would succeed, because the verification procedure didn't receive the "original" certificate but a fake one

Comment: If the verification succeeding in that case is a problem, then something is very fundamentally wrong in the design. All the verification checks is that the claimed data was signed with the claimed certificate. It *was* in that case. So the verification *should* succeed. (It's bad if someone can change my contract and leave my signature on it. But if they have to replace my signature with their own to change the contract, then that's fine. It's not my contract, but it doesn't even appear to have my signature. So no problem.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I rephrased my question

Comment: How would an attacker get his hands on a private key that corresponds to a certificate the system would consider valid? Wouldn't the system just say "that's not a certificate signed by any authority I recognize" and reject the data?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz by acquiring/buying a valid private key at any "authorized retailer". In the 1st approach, the system verifies 1) that the enclosed certificate is valid (correct certificate chain, not expired, not in a CRL, etc.) and 2) that the signature is correct and was generated with the private key corresponding to the enclosed certificate. Other than that, _any_ private key could be used for signing, not necessarily my own, and that's what worries me

Comment: Well then that's the problem. Your rules for deciding what constitutes a "valid certificate" (for purposes of accepting signatures as validating the contents as suitable for your use) are horribly broken. You need to change those rules.

Comment: I think you nailed it. Using the 1st approach and verifying that the common name in the certificate corresponds to _my_ domain and not other bogus domain should be enough; do you agree?

Comment: Assuming you also make sure the certificate was issued/signed by a CA you trust. The exact details about what certificates you should accept and what information you should determine about the origin of the data based on that depends upon the specifics of your application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first approach is better. Your concerns are misplaced. In the example you give, the verification *should* succeed. The data was indeed signed by the certificate it claims to have been signed by.

If I sign some document, then it's very important that it only appear to have my signature if it hasn't been tampered with. But if you can tamper with it but then have to put *your* signature on it, that's fine. You *did* sign its contents. I didn't, but it doesn't appear to have *my* signature. So that's fine.

You still must decide what that signature *means* of course after you decide it's basically valid. But that should be considered a separate step.

The design should be based on the fundamental security principle that an untrusted attacker cannot obtain the private key corresponding to the public key authorized by any certificate the system would accept as valid. Generally, it will be based on the common name in the certificate and the identity of the authority who signed it.

You can safely store the data, certificate, and signature together. This will allow you to validate the data and signature. The important thing is that you properly decide what that validation *means* by looking at the certificate.